# How foreach loop handle changes in non-binding collections? c#

Tags: java, c#, loops, iterator

As we all know, you can't modify a collection inside a foreach loop as the `InvalidOperationException`.

But how does the foreach loop checkouts any changes?

I mean, if I have this code:

```
foreach(var item in List<int> list) {
    list.Add(5);
    list.Remove(5);
}
```

...it still casts exception.

There is no any version control of the collection in the `IEnumerator` interface. So how does this work?

I am asking for this because in java you can modify the collection easily during loop, and this is the problem in my own `HashCollection<T>` implementation, and I have no idea how to checks any collection changes.

Comment: this is also not allowed in Java, it throws `ConcurrentModificationException`: https://ideone.com/CLf5Si || A counter is used in Java to check for *structural* modifications (`if (modCount != expectedModCount) { throw new ConcurrentModificationException(); }`

Comment: Source code of [`AbstractList`](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/542cc602a7f023d3351133a321c4fa57249b8765/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/AbstractList.java#L605)

Comment: @user16320675 - it was extemly helpful. Remove in enumerator dissapoints me...

Answer (score 1):

ok i found the answer

```
public class List<T> {
...
    public struct Enumerator : IEnumerator<T>, System.Collections.IEnumerator
        {
            private List<T> list;
            private int index;
            private int version; // there it is
            private T current;
 
            internal Enumerator(List<T> list) {
                this.list = list;
                index = 0;
                version = list._version;
                current = default(T);
            }
...
```

There the internal struct in List what i can't do in java. Probably i should declare open `Version` property and pass the collection inside Enumerator.

Comment: "the internal struct in List what i can't do in java": you can (not a struct but an object). See the implemenation of [`AbstractList.Itr`](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/542cc602a7f023d3351133a321c4fa57249b8765/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/AbstractList.java#L345)